# youtube movie-player returning undefined on methods getDuration() etc, unless invoked in browser

Tags: javascript, youtube-javascript-api, browser-extension

If I open youtube, navigate to a video and run the following in the browser console, it works flawlessly.

```
const video = document.getElementById("movie_player") 
video.getDuration()
```

If I'm making a chrome extension where the content script injects a button on the page at the document's end, and pressing the button executes the above code; it will give me undefined.

I'm not making my own iframe, I'm working with what's already on youtube.  And it doesn't seem to matter how long I wait for before I press the button, it will always give me undefined.

Are we supposed to use the youtube API v3 to deal with this? because I was under the impression that it was designed to be used for when you want to tinker with your own iframes.